# How can I find and add an ocx file to my vba project on office 2003 for resizing pictures

Tags: vba, activex

I want to load a JPEG or any kind of picture file from a database into an `activeX` control on a user form. I want the picture to resize to that of the `activeX` image control. There are a lot of times when I've used `ActiveX controls:Filepreview` where they sometimes need to be re-size because it is open larger once they've been clicked. How can I do this in VBA?
My objective is to find `.ocx` file which is using `activeX` control for image or picture to apply my project and then register it to the VBA finally find method or function resizing picture. On the form and be able to resize them when I choose one.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an `ActiveX` to your project;
- <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on free space of Toolbox;
- Select `Additional Controls ...`;
- From `Available controls` select your own;

If your favorite `ActiveX` not found in list, run this command line:

```
regsvr32 <file path and name>.ocx
```

After re-entering it should be added to list.